# How to get all products of a Shopify shop?

Tags: shopify, liquid

In my theme development, I don't find the way to get all the products of my shop.
Although, I can retrieve all the collections with the variable collections (exemple: `{% for c in collections %}`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this url: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/collections/change-catalog-page

Like magic... all your products...

Comment: While true, it is limited to you having to paginate by 50 or less, and you can't pull more than 50 anywhere else on the site either.

Comment: You can pull 250 with the API at once, and with pagination set to 1000 for example, front-end code can pull 1000. There is no limit of 50 unless you set that for yourself or do nothing.

Comment: "Don't paginate a collection by more than 50, that's the maximum amount of products you should query per page." according to their own documentation seen here: http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/paginate

Comment: Key word "should"

Answer (score 0):

Get all products at once or to run a query(API Request) for all products in shopify store : 
using this app is more managed -> https://github.com/phpish/shopify_private_app-skeleton so, my solution below is based on this app or you can relate the solution with your solution as well

```
<?php

session_start();

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpish\shopify;
require __DIR__.'/conf.php';

$shopify = shopify\client(SHOPIFY_SHOP, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD, true);

try
{
    $products = $shopify('GET /admin/products/count.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));

    $totalproducts = $shopify('GET /admin/products/count.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));
    $limit = 50;
    $totalpage = ceil($totalproducts/$limit);
    for($i=1; $i<=$totalpage; $i++){
        $products = $shopify('GET /admin/products.json?'.$limit.'=50&page='.$i, array('published_status'=>'published'));
        foreach($products as $product){
          //do anything at once for all the products in store
        }
     }
  }
  catch (shopify\ApiException $e)
  {
    //
  }
```

Summary : The idea is to retrieve with page=x as parameter. after calculating the number of pages we will have with specified limit i.e 50 at one time fetch.